# Why did these uniforms have that symbol?

Tags: star-wars, andor

In episodes 2 and 3 of *Andor*,

> a flashback to Cassian Andor's youth shows a freighter crashing on his homeworld of Kenari. Some crew stagger out, with clearly visible [Separatist/CIS insignia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Separatist_hex_icon) on their arms, and one of them is killed by blowguns:
>  [image: Screenshot showing a dead humanoid with a CIS emblem highlighted by a hand-drawn red circle]

> However, later, Maarva says that Cassian and the rest of his people won't be safe, since they just killed a "Republic officer".
>  [image: Screenshot of Maarva with the closed caption "Yeah, people who've just killed a Republic officer."]

Has this been officially addressed? Is this just a costuming error, the result of rewrites, or something else?

Comment: Military surplus, maybe?

Comment: @Valorum Republic officers in surplus CIS uniforms during the height of the Clone Wars seems like a really bad idea. Unless it was some kinda espionage deal... Although now I think about it, Boba Fett had that bait-and-switch with the speeder bike gang. Could be that Maarva is just lying through her teeth about it since Cassian eventually joins anti-Republic insurrectionists as a child in the near future.

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 Maybe, though Cassian doesn't even speak Basic at that point, so it seems like she'd have little reason to lie. B2EMO also identifies the (offscreen) incoming ship as Republic and says they should hurry up, and he'd have even less reason to lie.

Comment: @MiloP A good point. I wonder if there's not something we missed, maybe there's actually a Republic guy in there somewhere we just didn't notice?

Comment: Maybe she doesn't know what she's talking about

Comment: There is also an issue with the planet itself - people mention that it was "destroyed by an Imperial mining disaster" - but it is shown with young Cassian, being already destroyed, way before Empire was formed. Also Cassian was 3-6 years old during the Clone Wars, so these scenes you are mentioning, Kassa is older than that. So something fishy is going on here... But maybe when Marva is mentioning "killing a Republic officer" she is not referring to the situation that just happened, maybe the tribe done that earlier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is addressed by the starwars.com Episode Guide for Episode 3:

> [image]
>
> The flashbacks in this episode occur during the later years of the Republic, **prior to the start of the Clone Wars**, with Maarva and Clem worrying about an incoming Republic frigate interrupting their salvage operation. The dead crewers aboard the transport corsair wear uniforms with a symbol closely related to the **eventual Separatist Alliance**. Travel to Kenari will later be restricted by the Empire due to environmental disaster.
>
> (source: https://www.starwars.com/series/andor/andor-season-1-episode-3-episode-guide, Trivia Gallery image 1, emphasis added)

The implication is that the faction that the crew belongs to will eventually become the Separatist Alliance/CIS, but hasn't yet seceded from the Republic.